# Javascript deleteRule() fails to function properly

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently working on a simple javascript demo code and having some confusion.
I put two deleteRule() statements inside a for loop to delete css rules when click the "delete button". There are two css rules need to be deleted, however it can only delete css rule one at a time.

```
function deleteRule() {    
   let stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
   for (let i = 0; i < stylesheet.cssRules.length; i++) {                
      if (stylesheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === "p") {
         stylesheet.deleteRule(i);
      }
      if (stylesheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === ".price") {
         stylesheet.deleteRule(i);
      }
}
```

And I tried to put the second if statement into a separated for loop to delete rules, it only took one click to delete two rules, can someone help me to understand why the code above can't delete rules in one for loop? Any answers would be appreciated.

Here is the entire code:

javascript code:

```
document.querySelector("#insertRuleBtn").addEventListener("click", insertRule);
document.querySelector("#changeRuleBtn").addEventListener("click", changeRule);
document.querySelector("#deleteRuleBtn").addEventListener("click", deleteRule);
   
function insertRule() {    
   // Insert paragraph rule
   let stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
   stylesheet.insertRule("p { color: blue; }");
   stylesheet.insertRule(".price { font-weight: bold; }");
}

function changeRule() { 
   let stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
   for (let i = 0; i < stylesheet.cssRules.length; i++) {                
      if (stylesheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === "p") {
         let style = stylesheet.cssRules[i].style;        
         style.setProperty("color", "red");
      }
      
      if (stylesheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === ".price") {
         let style = stylesheet.cssRules[i].style; 
         style.setProperty("font-style","italic");
      }
   }
 }

**function deleteRule() {    
   // Delete the paragraph rule
   let stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
   for (let i = 0; i < stylesheet.cssRules.length; i++) {                
      if (stylesheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === "p") {
         stylesheet.deleteRule(i);
      }
      
      if (stylesheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === ".price") {
         stylesheet.deleteRule(i);
      }
   }**





}
```

css code:

```
body  {
   color: darkgreen;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#menu {
   background-color: moccasin;
   width: 200px;        
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 20px;
}
```

html code:

```
<body>
   <div id="menu">
      <h1>Menu</h1>
      <p>
         Ham sandwich - <span class="price">$5</span>
      </p>
      <p>
         Spinach salad - <span class="price">$4.50</span>
      </p>
      <p>
         Hamburger - <span class="price">$5.50</span>
      </p>
   </div>
   
   <p>
      <button id="insertRuleBtn">Insert Rule</button>
      <button id="changeRuleBtn">Change Rule</button>
      <button id="deleteRuleBtn">Delete Rule</button>      
   </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you delete a rule, your rule list is decreased by one, but your index `i` increases anyway. So on next iteration you won't be able to delete the appropriate rule.

To solve this, you can either just get all the indexes in one go and then delete them in loop.

Or alternatively, you can decrement the index when you delete an rule, to keep the index in sync -

```js
document.querySelector("#insertRuleBtn").addEventListener("click", insertRule);
document.querySelector("#changeRuleBtn").addEventListener("click", changeRule);
document.querySelector("#deleteRuleBtn").addEventListener("click", deleteRule);

function insertRule() {
  // Insert paragraph rule
  let stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
  stylesheet.insertRule("p { color: blue; }");
  stylesheet.insertRule(".price { font-weight: bold; }");
}

function changeRule() {
  let stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < stylesheet.cssRules.length; i++) {
    if (stylesheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === "p") {
      let style = stylesheet.cssRules[i].style;
      style.setProperty("color", "red");
    }

    if (stylesheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === ".price") {
      let style = stylesheet.cssRules[i].style;
      style.setProperty("font-style", "italic");
    }
  }
}

function deleteRule() {
  // Delete the paragraph rule
  let stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < stylesheet.cssRules.length; i++) {
    if (stylesheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === "p") {
      stylesheet.deleteRule(i--);
    } else if (stylesheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === ".price") {
      stylesheet.deleteRule(i--);
    }
  }





}
```

```css
body {
  color: darkgreen;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#menu {
  background-color: moccasin;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <p>
      Ham sandwich - <span class="price">$5</span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Spinach salad - <span class="price">$4.50</span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Hamburger - <span class="price">$5.50</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <p>
    <button id="insertRuleBtn">Insert Rule</button>
    <button id="changeRuleBtn">Change Rule</button>
    <button id="deleteRuleBtn">Delete Rule</button>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, in my experiment the first delete click causes "italic"(related to .price) to be removed and second click causes "red"(related to p) to be removed, however rule "italic" is at the index greater than "red". if index is the case, why "red" doesn't get removed first?

Comment: When you insert a new `css rule`, it is inserted at index `0`. So in your case the `italics` on `.price` is at index `0` which is before `red` on `p`.